# Find probability of certain number of cards being dealt from remaining cards

Tags: probability

I did find similar questions to this but I didn't understand the complex answers, so here goes:

I need to find the probability of being dealt a specified amount of cards from the remaining cards in the deck, for example:

I have being dealt 2 cards, Ace and King of clubs, there are now 50 cards remaining in the deck, 11 of which are clubs. I know I can find the probability of the next card dealt being a club by doing:

```
11 / 50 = 0.22 (22%)
```

But I need 3 more clubs to make my flush (5 cards of the same suit) and there are 5 cards to be dealt, how do I find the probabilty of being dealt 3 more clubs after 5 more cards have been dealt, would it be something like:

```
(11 / 50) + (11 / 49) + (11 / 48) + (11 / 47) + (11 / 46)
```

Comment: You also have to consider the probability of the rest of players not getting a club dealed.

Comment: Summation of probabilities only come in if we are dealing with events that are mutually exclusive. Also be aware that the sum exceeds $1$ so cannot be a probability.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well then $5$ cards are drawn from a deck of $50$ cards of which exactly $11$ are clubs.

Then the probability that *exactly* $3$ clubs are drawn equals:$$\frac{\binom{11}3\binom{39}2}{\binom{50}5}$$

If you are looking for the probability that *at least* $3$ clubs are drawn then see the answer of **Jfischer**.

Comment: Of course, it is possible to obtain three, four, or five additional clubs or five cards of another suit.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I wrongly said "spades" but meant "clubs' (repaired now). Are things okay now? I do not fully understand the question.

Comment: That is because the question is not well-written.  The OP seems to be assuming that the only way to obtain a flush if five additional cards are drawn is to obtain three additional clubs.  Of course, it is possible to obtain *at least* three clubs or obtain five cards of another suit.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you. Well, the OP is well informed now with the two answers.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig you are right, the possibility to draw 5 cards of a different color but all of them of the same color is not included in my response.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider clubs as one color and all other cards as another color. Hence you have a two color problem where you draw without replacement. Since you need at least 3 more clubs you also have to consider the cases where you draw 4 or 5 clubs.

So your probability is the sum of drawing exactly, 3,4 or 5 clubs equals
$$\dfrac{\binom{11}{3}\binom{39}{2}}{\binom{50}{5}}+\dfrac{\binom{11}{4}\binom{39}{1}}{\binom{50}{5}}+\dfrac{\binom{11}{5}\binom{39}{0}}{\binom{50}{5}}$$

Comment: Yes it's at least 3 clubs. Thanks for the answer, I'm not sure how to read it though, is the first bit: ((11 / 3) + (39 / 2)) / (50 / 5) ? Or are the top results multiplied?

Comment: They are multiplied and the objects $\binom{n}{k}$ are called the binomial coefficients. These are not fractions $\dfrac{11}{3}$.

Comment: Ok, so how do calculate the answer then? Sorry, I only know very basic maths, there must be a way to do this using simple multiplication/division? I just want to get a percentage chance.

Comment: The binomial coefficient is defined as $\binom{n}{k}=\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ where $n! := n\cdot(n-1)...2\cdot 1$. You can use for example wolframalpha.com to calculate the percentage in decimals. I do not see the additional value because the answer I gave is already perfectly valid.

Comment: Valid it may be but it's useless to me, I need to create a program that comes up with a simple percentage chance.

Comment: Well, that was firstly not part of your question. Secondly it is not useless since you can find the binomial coefficient in the math part of every major programming language (e.g. in Python: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.binom.html) or write a very easy program to calculate it.